# Migrating data over to BigQuery from Redshift

Tags: google-bigquery, amazon-redshift

I want to migrate 1 TB of data spread across ~100 tables from Redshift to BigQuery.

Are there any tools for this data migrations? If something like 'pgloader' (used to migrate from MySQL to PostgreSQL) is available it will save a lot of time?

Comment: This week on Reddit I saw that someone published on GitHub a tool to export data from RedShift to BigQuery https://github.com/uswitch/bqshift

Comment: Upvote to bqshift - I heard people were successful using it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

2019 update - now [officially supported](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/redshift-migration):

- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/redshift-migration

---

There are 2 open sources alternatives that I know of on GitHub:

- https://github.com/iconara/bigshift
- https://github.com/uswitch/bqshift

Both seem pretty well maintained, while bigshift has been around for a longer time and shows a more complete documentation (for now).

Quoting bigshift docs on why the tool is pretty useful when doing this migration:

> The CSV produced by Redshift's UNLOAD can't be loaded into BigQuery no
>   matter what options you specify on either end. Redshift can quote all
>   fields or none, but BigQuery doesn't allow non-string fields to be
>   quoted. The format of booleans and timestamps are not compatible, and
>   they expect quotes in quoted fields to be escaped differently, to name
>   a few things.
>
> This means that a lot of what BigShift does is make sure that the data
>   that is dumped from Redshift is compatible with BigQuery. To do this
>   it reads the table schema and translates the different datatypes while
>   the data is dumped. Quotes are escaped, timestamps formatted, and so
>   on.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I'm looking for.